# .net - How to add controls dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, repeater

I want to add dynamic controls

Like the below image I want to do

I am struggling to do that

If I click Add More Experience button I want to display another rows

[image]

I tried with user control but it is not working properly.

Below code is working fine but if I add controls then close the browser page and then open the browser again added controls are coming.

I think the problem is static int i=0;

```
static int i = 0;
    protected void addnewtext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            AddVisaControl ac = (AddVisaControl)Page.LoadControl("AddVisaControl.ascx");
            placeHolder.Controls.Add(ac);
            placeHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR>"));
        }
    }
```

Please provide your ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: IIRC Static variables will remain until the server restarts. Instead you will need to use another method, i.e. ViewState to store that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, when using a static variable within an ASP.Net page, it will be shared amongst all users until the application pool or server is restarted.

Instead you should really be using a ViewState or similar to read/write the value.

```
private int controlCount
{
    get 
    {
        int val = 0;
        try
        {
            val = (int)Page.ViewState["ControlCount"];
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // handle exception, if required.
        }
        return val;
    }
    set { Page.ViewState["ControlCount"] = value; }
}
protected void addnewtext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = controlCount++;
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        AddVisaControl ac = (AddVisaControl)Page.LoadControl("AddVisaControl.ascx");
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(ac);
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR>"));
    }
}
```